# C# remote Windows Service Startup Mode change

Tags: c#, service, remote-access, impersonation

I am an Administrator on a remote Windows 2008 R2 Enterprise server (SRV1) on the same domain as the computer I am currently logged on (Win7).

From my workstation, I can manually:
1) remote desktop to SRV1
2) use services.msc (locally) and then connect to SRV1

in order to change the startup type of a given Windows Service (e.g.: AudioSrv): Manual, Disabled, Automatic...  And it works.

Quuestion: I am trying to write a C# program which will run off my workstation, under my credentials and same domain, in order to change a Windows Service Startup Type on the server but it seems my permissions are not carried out.  I've been trying various things such as impersonation but none seems to work. I am able to Install, Remove, Start and Stop a remote service without any problem but the Startup Type thing fails.

Any idea?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7665/Extend-ServiceController-class-to-change-the-Start

It allows to change the Startup Mode on a remote machine without providing credentials within the code (as long as you have the right permissions on the remote host).